# Combining 2 loops into one loop

Tags: excel, vba

hi all this is my first time posting a question
i have 2 loop in my excel vba

loop 1 :

```
Dim Desktop_Analytics_Users As Range
Dim Desktop_Analytics_Sessions As Range
Dim Desktop_Analytics_PageViews As Range
Dim Desktop_Dfp_Impressions As Range
Dim Desktop_Dfp_Clicks As Range
Dim Desktop_Dfp_CTR As Range
Dim Mobile_Analytics_Users As Range
Dim Mobile_Analytics_Sessions As Range
Dim Mobile_Analytics_PageViews As Range
Dim Mobile_Dfp_Impressions As Range
Dim Mobile_Dfp_Clicks As Range
Dim Mobile_Dfp_CTR As Range
Dim Data As Variant
Dim CorantData As Variant



Set Desktop_Analytics_Users = Range("G9:G15,G19:G25,G29:G35,G39:G45,G49:G55")
Set Desktop_Analytics_Sessions = Range("H9:H15,H19:H25,H29:H35,H39:H45,H49:H55")
Set Desktop_Analytics_PageViews = Range("I9:I15,I19:I25,I29:I35,I39:I45,I49:I55")
Set Desktop_Dfp_Impressions = Range("J9:J15,J19:J25,J29:J35,J39:J45,J49:J55")
Set Desktop_Dfp_Clicks = Range("K9:K15,K19:K25,K29:K35,K39:K45,K49:K55")
Set Desktop_Dfp_CTR = Range("L9:L15,L19:L25,L29:L35,L39:L45,L49:L55")
Set Mobile_Analytics_Users = Range("N9:N15,N19:N25,N29:N35,N39:N45,N49:N55")
Set Mobile_Analytics_Sessions = Range("O9:O15,O19:O25,O29:O35,O39:O45,O49:O55")
Set Mobile_Analytics_PageViews = Range("P9:P15,P19:P25,P29:P35,P39:P45,P49:P55")
Set Mobile_Dfp_Impressions = Range("Q9:Q15,Q19:Q25,Q29:Q35,Q39:Q45,Q49:Q55")
Set Mobile_Dfp_Clicks = Range("R9:R15,R19:R25,R29:R35,R39:R45,R49:R55")
Set Mobile_Dfp_CTR = Range("S9:S15,S19:S25,S29:S35,S39:S45,S49:S55")

Data = Array(Desktop_Analytics_Users, Desktop_Analytics_Sessions, Desktop_Analytics_PageViews, Desktop_Dfp_Impressions, Desktop_Dfp_Clicks, Desktop_Dfp_CTR _
       , Mobile_Analytics_Users, Mobile_Analytics_Sessions, Mobile_Analytics_PageViews, Mobile_Dfp_Impressions, Mobile_Dfp_Clicks, Mobile_Dfp_CTR)

 For Each CorantData In Data
    min = Application.WorksheetFunction.min(CorantData)
    max = Application.WorksheetFunction.max(CorantData)
Next CorantData
```

this loop goes through a series of ranges in order to find the max and min values

loop 2:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim chs As ChartObject

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    For Each chs In sh.ChartObjects
        chs.Activate
        ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
        ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = min
        ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = max
    Next chs
```

this loop selects every chart and set the max and min axes.

my goal is to combine the 2, but with no successes.

i need to go throw each range and determine the max and min values then select the chart and set these values in the axes.

the ranges & the charts are arranged in the same order.

I would appreciate any help on the subject

Comment: The `.Select` statement isn't needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `For` loop

```
Data = Array( ... )  ' Creates a 0 bound array

Dim chs as ChartObject
For i=1 To sh.ChartObjects.Count
    Set chs = sh.ChartObjects(i)
    min = Application.WorksheetFunction.min(Data(i-1))
    max = Application.WorksheetFunction.max(Data(i-1))        
    chs.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = min
    chs.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = max
Next i
```

Comment: thank you John i have manged to make adjustments to my cod, and it works. Sadly, I don't really understand how exactly it works , Plus if I try to use `data = array(...)` i get compile error: expected: identifier or bracketed expression so i just left it as seen in my cod above.  i have no idea what is a ' Creates a 0 bound array

Comment: I have no training in vba all my knowledge is gained in trial and error.
Is there an article you can refer me to get a deeper understanding of the - "a 0 bound array" ?

Comment: Read here: https://bettersolutions.com/vba/arrays/upper-lower-bounds.htm The `Array()` function creates an array where the first element is accessed by `data(0)` instead of `data(1)`. This is what a `0 bound array` is. One where the first element is at position 0. This is why I am using `data(i-1)` in my code since my loop goes from `1` to `n`, instead of from `0` to `n-1`.